# MongoTemplate: remove list of elements returned from `find`

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

I am calling `MongoTemplate.find(query, type)` which returns a `List<T>`. My question, how do I remove all elements in the list from the DB Collection in one DB call. I know I could create a `Query` manually using `id` if I know the structure of `T` but what if I don't know what `T` is.

`MongoTemplate` has a `remove` method that I can pass `T`. What I need is the equivalent `removeAll(Collection<T> items, Class<T> type)`

**EDIT per answer**

I need to process each element and determine which ones to remove so I cannot simply pass the `Query` to `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling [find(Query, Class)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#find%28org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query,%20java.lang.Class%29) and then remove all returned documents (a Collection or one-by-one), you can simply call [remove(Query, Class)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#remove%28org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query,%20java.lang.Class%29). It's much better that way since you don't have to return all documents to the client, but issue a remove query in the DB itself.

Comment: I need to process each element and determine which ones to remove.

Comment: The `Query` defines which documents you want to remove